# RookIO AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume

Tags: kubernetes, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I have Kubernetes 1.18 with rookio setup, this pod was running for sometime. one of the node went out of `Ready` status for some reason. I rebooted the node, now its in `Ready` status.

But Pod stuck on `ContainerCreating` status. its waiting to mount the rookio `PVC`.

**Pod status**

```
# kgp |grep -v Running
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
redis-slave-0                                               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          14h
```

**PodEvents**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                      From                     Message
  ----     ------              ----                     ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedMount         23m (x69 over 13h)       kubelet, node05       Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[redis-data config redis-tmp-conf default-token-lqpgm health]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount         19m (x95 over 13h)       kubelet, node05       Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[health redis-data config redis-tmp-conf default-token-lqpgm]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount         14m (x79 over 13h)       kubelet, node05       Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[default-token-lqpgm health redis-data config redis-tmp-conf]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount         5m45s (x66 over 13h)     kubelet, node05       Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[config redis-tmp-conf default-token-lqpgm health redis-data]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  2m44s (x101 over 6h32m)  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-e854eee7-0a36-4a92-ba61-f9e6e976f64c" : attachdetachment timeout for volume 0001-0009-rook-ceph-0000000000000002-0c4a5173-e8a7-11ea-9bd1-0637030c9151
```

PVC attach status set to `false`

```
 kubectl get volumeattachment |grep -v true  
NAME                                                                   ATTACHER                     PV                                         NODE        ATTACHED   AGE
csi-3424d1bdc5212aeef30e681c9d99df38dd68fdabb47e5f820125c90d54d61d7b   rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com   pvc-e854eee7-0a36-4a92-ba61-f9e6e976f64c   node05   false      14h
```

I try to move the pod to different node, still same issue.

**PV and PVC status**

```
# k describe pv pvc-e854eee7-0a36-4a92-ba61-f9e6e976f64c
Name:            pvc-e854eee7-0a36-4a92-ba61-f9e6e976f64c
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    rook-ceph-block
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/redis-data-redis-slave-0
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        287Mi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com
    FSType:            ext4
    VolumeHandle:      0001-0009-rook-ceph-0000000000000002-0c4a5173-e8a7-11ea-9bd1-0637030c9151
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      clusterID=rook-ceph
                           imageFeatures=layering
                           imageFormat=2
                           imageName=csi-vol-0c4a5173-e8a7-11ea-9bd1-0637030c9151
                           journalPool=replicapool
                           pool=replicapool
                           radosNamespace=
                           storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity=1598460149789-8081-rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com



 k describe pvc redis-data-redis-slave-0
Name:          redis-data-redis-slave-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  rook-ceph-block
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-e854eee7-0a36-4a92-ba61-f9e6e976f64c
Labels:        app=redis
               component=slave
               heritage=Helm
               release=redis
               role=slave
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      287Mi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    redis-slave-0
Events:        <none>
```

How to fix this mount issue?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the PV and Node in the same zone(availability zones in AWS). If they are in different zones the PV will not attach to the node.

To resolve this simply delete the PV and PVC and recreate it, it will create the new PV in the same zone as node.